# my app does not recognize notification and alarm i set up?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I am trying to set my app to send the user a notification at the same time every day. I set the time around the time I ran the app so it shows when i run the app on my emulator. But it shows that there is an alarm set but it does not show the notification I set?
I made an Alarm.java class to hold the alarm manager, and then added the notification in my Main.java class in the onCreate method.

This is my Alarm.java class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class Alarm extends Activity {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Alarm.this , Main.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Alarm.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, today.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours

    }



}
```

this is the notification from my MainActivity.java class

```
nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notify=new Notification(R.drawable.feet,"Almost here!",today.getTimeInMillis());
    CharSequence from="Here!";
    CharSequence message=arriving.getText().toString();
    Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this,Main.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(Main.this,0,intent,0);
    Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(Main.this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle(from);
    builder.setContentTitle(message);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fee);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.build();

    notify=builder.getNotification();
    nm.notify(0,notify);
    finish();
```

PS.I put my intent Main.this and Main.class because I wanted to call the Main class, with the user input saved when the notification was clicked on, but when I click the notification, it opens the Main class but without what the user put in previously.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the notification code, you have `setContentTitle(String)` back-to-back. Android requires that you have the Icon, Title and Text. I think you autocompleted? Try replacing one with `setContentText(String)`. Hope that solves it.

Comment: it cleared some of my problems! thanks! for the text, it didn't show. i'm thinking its cos its a getText () method, I'm not sure, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a good look at the Notifications site for Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).